# Microservice architecture in game client

Tags: architecture, mmo

We can use microservice architecture for backend in mmo games, like one service for auth, one for chat, etc

But can(or should) we use same architecture for client part in mmo games?

One service for rendering, one for physics, one for chat, one for character creation, service for any game feature, etc

And any service can be written in any language you want and use messaging for communication

Comment: You can use any architecture you like and that you find helps you achieve your goals. When you prototype the microservice-based client you have in mind, does it perform as desired, or do you encounter a problem along the way that you need help solving?

Comment: @DMGregory so far only issue is that create window(window service) in one process and draw into it from another(rendering service) is hard(or impossible?) to achieve

Comment: Want to edit your question to ask about how to solve that problem specifically? You'll tend to get better, more useful/actionable answers from questions that ask "how can I solve X?" than from [questions that ask "is solution X a good idea?"](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2808/39518).